# NodeJS: Having trouble using promises

Tags: javascript, node.js

Whenever I run this, I get an error `Error: It broke`

Why doesn't this work? I feel like everything is done right, but the error pops up maybe a bit quicker than it should.

```
const steam = require('steamidconvert')(config.steamapi)
const axios = require('axios');
const jp = require('jsonpath')


var steamid64;
var customid;
var logIds;
var steamid;

var getSteamIDs = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    if (args[0] == "") {
        message.channel.send("Error, you need to enter a link to your steam profile after !me (e.g. !me https://steamcommunity.com/id/ElkYT)")
    } else {
        if (args[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("steamcommunity.com/id".toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            if (args[0].slice(-1) == "/") {
                customid = args[0].slice((args[0].indexOf("d")) + 2, args[0].lastIndexOf(args[0].slice(-1)))
            } else {
                customid = `${args[0].slice((args[0].indexOf("d")) + 2, args[0].lastIndexOf(args[0].slice(-1)))}${args[0].slice(-1)}`
            }
            steam.convertVanity(customid, function (err, res) {
                if (err) {
                    message.channel.send(`ERROR: Couldn't fetch Steam profile!`);
                    console.log(err)
                }
                steamid64 = res
                steamid = steam.convertToText(steamid64)
            })
        } else if (args[0].toLowerCase().indexOf("steamcommunity.com/profiles".toLowerCase()) != -1) {
            if (args[0].slice(-1) == "/") {
                steamid64 = args[0].slice((args[0].indexOf("l")) + 4, args[0].lastIndexOf(args[0].slice(-1)))
                steamid = steam.convertToText(steamid64)
            } else {
                steamid64 = `${args[0].slice((args[0].indexOf("l")) + 4, args[0].lastIndexOf(args[0].slice(-1)))}${args[0].slice(-1)}`
                steamid = steam.convertToText(steamid64)
            }
        }
    }
    if (steamid64) {
        resolve(steamid64);

    } else {
        reject(Error("It broke"))
    }
});

function getLogIDs(steamid64) {
    console.log('steamid64: ',steamid64)
    axios.get('http://logs.tf/json_search?player=' + steamid64 + '&limit=10')
        .then(response => {
            logIds = (jp.query(response.data, '$..logs[*].id'));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
}

getSteamIDs.then(function(data) {
    getLogIDs(data);
  }).then(function() {
    console.log(logIds);
  });
```

Thank you so much in advance :)

Edit 1: changed code to be all of my actual code instead of a simplification/example of my code, sorry

Comment: just put a return before `axios.get` in `getLogIDs`

Comment: what would it be returning? im confused

Comment: what do you want to do? your code is very wrong!

Comment: I cut down a lot of the actual code just because it was a lot to read (mostly the getSteamIDs part) but I want to run getLogIDs after getSteamIDs finishes so I can use the variable steamid64 in it

Answer (score 0):

The error message, presumably, says something like "Can't access property `then` on `undefined`.

This means that `getSteamIDs(steamid64)` is `undefined` (i.e. the return value of calling that function). It says nothing about `steamid64`.

And `getSteamIDs(steamid64)` **is** `undefined`, the function:

> ```
> function getSteamIDs() {
>   steamid64 = 1234567890
> }
> ```

… has no `return` statement, so it returns `undefined`.

`then()` is a method you find on promises and you don't even create a promise inside the `getSteamIDs` function.

Comment: I changed my post to be my actual code and the progress I've made on it and I'm getting a different error now that I'm using an actual promise (see edit)

Comment: @ElkTF2 — That code is so different, you should ask a new question.